# Getting Excel 2003 to interpret a pasted number with leading zeros as text (works fine in 2007)

Tags: excel

I know there are other similar threads on SO, but they suggest formating the cells to text and/or prefixing the cells with a '.

I've done them both, and it works fine in Excel 2007, but when I open the exact same Excel template in Excel 2003 and paste the same source, it removes the leading zeros. Are there any other possibilities? Could one make a macro something?

EDIT: I found a solution for a different problem that solves this as well. [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980063/pasting-the-same-text-copied-from-different-sources-behaves-differently-in-excel). Record a macro that uses 'Paste Special' as text, and override ctrl-v on that spreadsheet.

Comment: Where is the data being pasted from?

Comment: Further, what it the precise formatting on the cells prior to pasting? The above works just fine on my Excel 2003.

Comment: That is also one of the problems: it differs. Sometimes there is space between some of the numbers, and other times it is not. It could also be copied from a lot of different sources, so formating may tag along as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a leading ' then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just select cells with data, right click, choose format, select custom and type the same number of zeros that You want to display (it is better explained [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2267850_leading-zeros-fixedlength-number-excel.html)).

Comment: It might be good enough in this case, but sometimes it's not sufficient. If you've a field representing an ID like 0012345, Excel might display 0012345 but the underlying data is still 12345 - which is wrong, and you may fail lookups/processing as a result. It's better to load the data correctly than try to fix it afterwards.